# How to get data as byte[] using GridFS Java API?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am using `Java-driver 2.13`. GridFS takes input as `File`, `InputStream` or `byte[]` in `createFile()` method on `GridFS` instance to create `GridFSInputFile` .

But when I tried to fetch data back I do have option only as `File` or `outputStream` using `GridFSDBFile.writeTo()` method.

I want to get data as `byte[]`. Is there any direct way in GridFS API or I need to manually convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method that returns a byte[] array, but you can use a ByteArrayOutputStream to achieve a similar effect:

```
GridFSDBFile file = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
file.writeTo(baos);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

To avoid unnecessary memory allocation, you can pass an initial size to the ByteArrayOutputStream constructor based on the length of the GridFS file, but note that the length is a long while the ByteArrayOutputStream constructor takes an integer.  You can also subclass ByteArrayOutputStream to get direct access to its protected buf field, as the toByteArray method does create a copy of the internal buffer.